# match any character behind / (front shash)

Tags: regex

can someone please quickly help me with regularexpression to match any character and group it which is coming behind front shash:

```
ae-app001/UK/Server/company
```

in this i want to match ae-app001 only.

the format remains the same except that we dont know how many slash might be there,
sometimes the string might be just :

```
ae-app001/UK/Server
```

so i need a generic regex which will match string1 in the below:

```
string1/string2/string3/string4 
string1/string2/string3
```

etc..

Comment: You can use `^[^\/]+` [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/flbbZp/1) Capture any character one or more other than `/` from start

Comment: I think the title of your question is a bit confusing. Looking at the required result, do you mean `Match any character before the first forward slash`?

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi perfect thanks you so much!!!!

Comment: @Thefourthbird sorry for the confussion,
you said it correctly. Match any character before the first forward slash
and i tried to explain in the discription.

Answer (score 0):

`/^([^\/]+)/` [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/BMX3G1/1)

But what if there's no slashes? Is it ok to capture whole string?

Comment: yes its ok to capture the whole string

Comment: string1-string2

i want regex to match string1 and string2 and group them in different groups.

Comment: (.*)-(.*) - is this good ? please suggent me the good way of doing this

Comment: A better one would be `([^-]*)-([^-]*)` [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/oqW53m/1) Depending upon if you have more than one hyphen, and the kind of behavior required, your regex may have to be tuned